# Django LoginView can not authenticate the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a LoginView and a registration form. this registration form is working properly, users are flying to the database, but LoginView gives an incorrect login or password when trying to log in, although all the data is correct, why can this be?

**CustomUser from models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()

    username = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=150,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "Пользователь с таким ником уже есть"},)
    email = models.EmailField(
        'почта',
        unique=True,
        blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(
        'пароль',
        max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        'имя',
        max_length=30,
        blank=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(
        'фамилия',
        max_length=30,
        blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(
        'день рождения',
        blank=True,
        null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
```

urls.py

```
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='user/login.html'),
        name='login'),
```

register

```
def registrations(request):
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        CustomUser.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data).save()
        messages.success(request, 'Вы успешно зарегестрировались')
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/reg.html', context)
```

It is necessary for LoginView to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that password are correctly hashed after the registration?

If you are not using the forms in `django.contrib.auth` you need to manually create and verify password:

See

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers